# How can I prove the convexity of $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ by using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'd like to prove that the function $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, with $x> 0$ is convex. Actually, I already know it's convex because I have studied its derivatives but I'd like to give a more "formal" prove by using convex definition, that is:

Let be $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. The function f is said to be convex in $S$ if $\forall x,y \in S$ and $\forall \lambda \in (0,1)$ the following holds:

$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$

I know that I should prove this:

$$(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \leq \lambda x^{-\frac{1}{3}}+(1-\lambda)y^{-\frac{1}{3}} $$

But I don't know what can I do in order to do it.

Any help would be aprecciated!

Comment: Are you sure $\lambda \in S$ ...? I suppose you meant $\forall \lambda \in [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'll edit it now

Comment: Minor fix: an arrow representing a mapping or approaching a value is better represented with a LaTeX symbol `\to`, which renders as $\to$, not a 'minus greater-than' pair.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the \Rightarrow command but clearly it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean $x>0$? Otherwise it is not convex.

Comment: Yes, I did. I corrected it now, thanks!

Comment: It's fine if you want to use the secant test as an exercise, but there's nothing wrong with a derivative test. It's perfectly "formal" to do so. In fact, I could argue thusly: $f''(x)=(4/9)x^{-7/3}$, which is positive for all $x>0$; therefore, $f(x)$ is convex; therefore, $f(\lambda x-(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ for all $x,y>0$ and all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:, As $t \mapsto t^3$ is increasing, we may cube both sides and replace $x, y$ with $a^3, b^3$ to equivalently prove:
$$ \left(\frac{\lambda}a +  \frac{1-\lambda}b \right)^3 (\lambda a^3 + (1-\lambda) b^3) \geqslant 1 \tag{$\star$}$$
which follows from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) ...

--

**P.S.** Hölder's inequality for our case (positive numbers $a, b, x, y$ and $p, q > 0$ s.t. $1/p + 1/q = 1$.
$$(x_1^p + x_2^p)^{1/p} (y_1^q+y_2^q)^{1/q} \geqslant x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$$
Now if we let $x_1 = (\lambda/a)^{3/4}, x_2 = ((1-\lambda)/b)^{3/4}$, $y_1 = (\lambda a^3)^{1/4}, y_2 = ((1-\lambda)b^3)^{1/4}$ with $p = 4/3, q = 4$, we get:
\begin{align} 
\left(\frac{\lambda}a +  \frac{1-\lambda}b \right)^{3/4} (\lambda a^3 + (1-\lambda) b^3)^{1/4} & \geqslant \left(\frac{\lambda}{a}\right)^{3/4}\left( \lambda a^3\right)^{1/4} + \left(\frac{1-\lambda}{b}\right)^{3/4}\left((1- \lambda) b^3\right)^{1/4} \\&= \lambda+(1-\lambda) = 1
\end{align}
which is essentially $(\star)$.

Comment: Did not you just want to say '[Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_conjugate_H.C3.B6lder_exponents)' instead of 'Holder's inequality'?

Comment: @MathOverview  No.  I used Hölder's inequality.  Can be done using others like AM-GM of course, but this seemed easiest.

Comment: Could you give me a hint to apply the Hölder's inequality in this case? I checked the link given but I'm a bit confused as it appears described in terms of norms and I can't see how we can use it to apply it in our case.

Comment: @marisa Have added detail to illustrate the specific application of Hölder's inequality above.

Comment: BTW I find it easier to remember Hölder's inequality in the form $$(a + b +  ...)^m (x + y +  ...)^n \geqslant ((a^mx^n)^{1/(m+n)} + (b^m y^n)^{1/(m+n)} + ... )^{m+n}  $$ with $m, n$ naturals.  Of course they need not be restricted to naturals, but it helps me recall better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, couldn't one just use the facts that

- for $x_1,x_2 >0, t \in [0,1]: \\
   -  t x_1 + (1-t)  x_2 >0 \\
   -  t x_1 + (1-t)  x_2 \ge t x_1  \\
   -  t x_1 + (1-t) x_2 \ge (1-t) x_2  $
- $u>0 \rightarrow u^{1/3}>0$
- $u,v>0 , u \ge v \rightarrow u^{1/3} \ge v^{1/3}$

and finally

- $u,v>0 , u \ge v \rightarrow u^{-1} \leq v^{-1}$